# What is a MYSQL formula that produces a truncated julian day?

Tags: mysql

I want a simple formula that will result in a Truncated Julian Day as part of a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
SELECT (TO_DAYS(date_column) - TO_DAYS('1968-05-24'))
```

With some help from:
http://www.csgnetwork.com/juliantruncdateconv.html